# Output of Flexcards/Dataraptor not visible to the other users

Tags: lightning-record-page, omnistudio

Does anyone know how make the output of Flexcards/Dataraptor visible to the other profiles? I created a flexcard and Dataraptor and added it to the record page but the output is only visible to the System Administrator and not to the other profiles. Is there a permission or access needs to modify? anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!.

System Administrator
[image]

Standard User
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.